How are Schwinger functions defined as moments if they are actually operators?
Let $\mu$ be a measure on the space of tempered distributions. Assuming $\mu$ satisfies some other properties, then it is the measure of a quantum field in a Euclidean framework. The Schwinger functions can be defined as moments of this measure,
$$S_n(f_1, \ldots, f_n) = \int_{\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)}\phi(f_1)\cdots\phi(f_n) d\mu(\phi) \tag{1}$$
where the $f_i$ are fixed test functions.
If $\phi$ is an ordinary tempered distribution (i.e. it takes values in $\mathcal{C}$ then the above integral is well defined if $\mu$ is. But in rigorous approaches to quantum field theory the quantum fields are taken to be operator valued distributions, so after fixing test functions the integrand in (1) are all operators. How can we rigorously make sense of (1) in this case?

You can use (1) to produce operator-valued distributions $f\mapsto \widehat{\phi}(f)$ where $\widehat{\phi}(f)$ is the multiplication operator on $H=L^2(S',d\mu)$ which sends a functional $\phi\mapsto F(\phi)$ to the new functional $\phi\mapsto \phi(f) F(\phi)$. Still better is to do that not for the measure $\mu$ on $S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but for $\nu$ on $S'(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$ where $\nu$ is the direct image measure of $\mu$ by the restriction map. This is because the $L^2$ space then is the physical Hilbert space of the QFT.

A good test case is $n=1$, i.e., quantum mechanics with one degree of freedom. The $\widehat{\phi}(f)$ should be an unbounded operator as in QM. The $\nu$ version should give you the position operator $\widehat{X}$ of your quantum mechanical 1d particle.

@AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you for all your helpful comments. Would you be able to elaborate on how we use (1) to define the multiplication operator $\hat{\phi}$? I don't see the role of (1) in the construction you described.

Perhaps this is not what you were asking, but just in case: The measure-theoretic formalism that you are describing is that of Euclidean field theory. It is not quantum mechanics, and the field is not a quantum mechanical observable but instead is a classical random variable. Thus everything commutes and you can reasonably apply probability theory/measure theory. In particular, the $\phi(f)$s you're looking at are not operator-valued distributions (except perhaps in the trivial sense that they're commuting operators on some probability space). Instead, you could say that they are random variable-valued distributions.
The key idea is that if one can construct these classical Euclidean fields, then under reasonable assumptions (namely the Osterwalder-Schrader axioms or their relatives), then one can obtain from them operator valued distributions which are the Wightman fields that we seek as the final product of the theory. This reconstruction is nontrivial and comes down to some delicate analytic continuation of the Schwinger functions.

Thank you. I am surprised as I always thought that Schwinger functions were operator value distributions. Every textbook I've read seems to gloss over these details, do you know of any source that goes over this in detail?

The connection between Schwinger functions and Euclidean fields is nontrivial. That is, it's not necessarily true that any system of Schwinger functions for a Wightman field are moments of some measure. For conditions for which they are, you might be interested in Nelson's axioms for Euclidean field theory. A very nice account can be found in Barry Simon's P(phi)_2 book.

Also just to clarify language- Schwinger functions are just honest tempered distributions. The same goes for the Wightman functions. The distinction about random variables/operator-valued distributions deals with the fields themselves.

I think I see the mistake I was making. The Schwinger functions are defined as a vacuum expectation value $$\langle \Omega | \phi(f_1)\cdots\phi(f_n) | \Omega \rangle$$ and thus are ordinary complex valued tempered distributions. I assume the same holds for Wightman functions.

What is confusing me is that we define the quantum field $\phi$ as an operator valued distribution, but in the integrand of (1) $\phi$ is an ordinary tempered distribution. How do we get an operator valued distribution from (1) or its Minkowski counterpart? From my understanding, the OS reconstruction theorem still treats the Wightman functions as ordinary distributions.

You take the Euclidean fields and compute their moments. These are Schwinger functions, which are ordinary tempered distributions. You analytically continue these tempered distributions to obtain lorentz covariant tempered distributions, which you prove satisfy the Wightman axioms for Wightman functions. Finally you can use the Wightman reconstruction theorem to construct an operator valued distribution acting on a hilbert space. You can more directly construct a Wightman field directly from a Euclidean field if you have some stronger structure such as that implied by Nelson's axioms

The tl;dr is that you assume additional structure and regularity so that you construct a Hamiltonian acting on the time-zero Hilbert space of the Euclidean field. Then you can create a Wightman field by taking $\int e^{iHt} \phi(f_t)e^{-iHt}dt$

Thank you very much for all your help!

The correspondence between the operator/Hilbert space langauge and the measure theoretic language is the essence of the Feynman-Kac isomorphism between Euclidean quantum field theory (the analytic continuation from $d$ space and one time dimension minkowski space to "imaginary time) and statistical field theory in d+1 dimensions.  It is how Ken Wilson simultaneously explained the universality of second-order phase transitions and made clear the origin on the divergences in in Feyman diagram calculations.

The analytic continuation from Minkowski space to Euclidean space is clear to me, but how does this change the quantum fields from being operator valued to random variable-valued?

Mapping matrix elements of operators  to integrals over random variables is exactly  what Feynman's  path integral does.
